# group by clause on data

Tags: sql, oracle

how to write a query to select the student_id and Sum the amount paid for course attendance, grouped by student

the table:

```
SQL> desc attendances
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- -------------
 RUNNING_ID                                         NUMBER(5)
 STUDENT_ID                                         NUMBER(4)
 EVALUATION                                         VARCHAR2(1)
 AMOUNT_PAID                                        NUMBER(6,2)
```

I have managed to get to this point, then I'm running into errors:

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT_PAID)
FROM ATTENDANCES;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if I got you right this is something what you want

```
SELECT student_id,SUM(AMOUNT_PAID)
FROM ATTENDANCES group by student_id;
```